# Nuxt3 Unexpected token '||='

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have problem
when i use this command

```
npm run dev
```

or

```
npx nuxi dev
```

after click on localhost link i get 500 error page
you can see this in hello world example : https://v3.nuxtjs.org/examples/essentials/hello-world/

what is problem ?

```
npm run dev
```

i get 500 error page : Unexpected token '||='

i should redirect to my app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using node `v14` and not [NodeJS' LTS](https://nodejs.org/en/) aka `v18` as of today while this is required regarding the [official doc](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/installation#prerequisites).
Install at least `v16` and it should be working better, preferably with [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

Reason is that: [Logical OR assignment aka ||=](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment#browser_compatibility) is available only from Node v15.